# Why is this code complaining about my function not being a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code shown below produces this error:

```
x.authenticate(...).allDomains(...).myDomains is not a function
```

There is an up arrow (^) under the 'm' in "myDomains". I don't recognize this as being any of the usual patterns for producing this error. Can someone please tell me how I can fix this problem? Thanks.

```js
#!/usr/bin/node

const allDomainsURL = 'https://77.247.183.107/domain/List?
const myDomainsURL = 'https://77.247.183.107/domain/Info?ApiKey=testapi&Password=testpass&Domain=[{*domain*}]&ResponseFormat=JSON';
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0; // Fixes "unable to verify the first certificate" error.
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

var domains = function() {

    this.dataObj = {
        'account' : '123456',
        'password': 'secret',
        'scratch' : [],
        'access'  : false,
        'data'    : {}
    };

    this.authenticate = function(dataObj) {
        this.dataObj.access = true;
        console.log('authenticate done.');
        return this;
    }

    this.allDomains = async function(dataObj) {
        const response = await fetch(allDomainsURL);
        this.dataObj.scratch = await response.json();
        this.dataObj.scratch = this.dataObj.scratch.domain;
        return this;
    }

    this.myDomains = async function(dataObj) {
        return this;
    }
}

var x = new domains();
x.authenticate('123456', 'secret').allDomains().myDomains();
```

// Error: TypeError: x.authenticate(...).allDomains(...).myDomains is not a function

Comment: you made it async, so allDomains returns a Promise

Comment: It would help if this was syntactically correct for a start. The syntax highlighting is all over the place here.

Comment: See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description): Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `allDomains` is an `async` function.  That means it returns a promise.  So, when you try to do:

```
x.authenticate('123456', 'secret').allDomains().myDomains();
```

You're trying to call `.myDomains()` on a promise and that method does not exist on a promise.

Remember, an `async` function ALWAYS returns a promise.  The value you `return` in an `async` function just becomes the resolved value of that promise.

---

FYI, it is not easy to support the chaining of asynchronous methods.  I'd suggest a different design structure if that's what you're trying to do.  In this case, you can do this:

```
await x.authenticate('123456', 'secret').allDomains();
await x.myDomains();
```

P.S. Your `authenticate` method is only designed to accept one argument and the code you show doesn't even use that argument, yet you are passing it two arguments in your example, so something is not correct there.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Your comments were very helpful.  You're right, I was trying to experiment with both fuction chaining and fetch at the same time.  Probably not a good idea.  The authenticate method was just a stub for use when password authentication is added.  I definitely see how that could be confusing.  "The value you return in an async function just becomes the resolved value of that promise" - Key piece of info.  Thanks.